# BigDecimal type convertion in Kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

So as always im pretty new to kotlin and android and i am creating an application where i need to store some monetary values in a Room database. This is my class:

```
 @Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "tblDash")
data class Dash(

@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
var id: Int,

@ColumnInfo(name = "distance")
var distance: Long,

@ColumnInfo(name = "revenue")
var revenue: BigDecimal,

@ColumnInfo(name = "date")
var date: Date
): Parcelable
```

that's basically all the code I have but when i try to run the app i get this error code :

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

so what i'd like is if someone could point me in the right direction on how i could convert this bigdecimal to whatever it need to be converted.

Comment: Use a `@TypeConverter` - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data - just make sure you use a `String` representation inside the database when using `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to string

```
class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromBigDecimal(value: BigDecimal): String {
        return value.toString()
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToBigDecimal(value: String): BigDecimal {
        return BigDecimal(value)
    }
}

@Database(entities = [], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
 
}
```

documentation -> https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Im not sure yet to implement your code but it gave me some direction I appreciate it.

Comment: just add the converters class to RoomDatabase() class like I showed, room will handle the rest you don't need to change other fields